# Why might an ssh client written in golang hang?

Tags: go, ssh

I'm running an ssh client to execute a command remotely on a virtual router. Some commands are executed, but when executing others, the ssh client hangs. The session on the router does not close. And the address is not displayed in the Host field. If you use putty or a windows ssh client, then everything is fine. How to fix it?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/crypto/ssh"
)

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) < 4 {
        log.Fatalf("Usage: %s <user> <host:port> <command>", os.Args[0])
    }

    client, session, err := connectToHost(os.Args[1], os.Args[2])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    command := strings.Join(os.Args[3:], " ")
    log.Printf("Exec command '%s'", command)
    out, err := session.CombinedOutput(command)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(string(out))
    client.Close()
}

func connectToHost(user, host string) (*ssh.Client, *ssh.Session, error) {
    var pass string
    fmt.Print("Password: ")
    fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &pass)

    sshConfig := &ssh.ClientConfig{
        User: user,
        Auth: []ssh.AuthMethod{ssh.Password(pass)},
    }
    sshConfig.HostKeyCallback = ssh.InsecureIgnoreHostKey()

    client, err := ssh.Dial("tcp", host, sshConfig)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    session, err := client.NewSession()
    if err != nil {
        client.Close()
        return nil, nil, err
    }

    return client, session, nil
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You don't implement a terminal. Interactive commands (like editors, password prompt ...) usually expect user input via a [terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4126/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-a-terminal-a-shell-a-tty-and-a-con) though.

Comment: Thanks for the line of thought, but why do some show commands work and others don't? In each of these cases, no user interaction is required. In this case, the program works correctly with Cisco csr1000.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Steffen Ullrich, he suggested a solution. This piece of code helped solve the problem

```
    modes := ssh.TerminalModes{
        ssh.TTY_OP_ISPEED: 14400,
        ssh.TTY_OP_OSPEED: 14400, 
    }

    if err := session.RequestPty("xterm", 80, 40, modes); err != nil {
        session.Close()
        return nil, nil, err
    }
```